# Unable to click the Link in selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to Click on Link. But it is showing Element Not found Message. Here is my HTML Code:
 `<a id="expTo" class="formblue_link padRight10 
 exportLinkActive" style="display: block; margin-left: -50px; margin-bottom: -20px;" href="javascript:;"> Export To</a>`

My code is:

```
        `driver.findElement(By.linkText("Export To")).click();`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until element visible and clickable as below :-

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("expTo"))).click();
```

**Note** :- Before going to find this element, make sure it is not inside any `frame/iframe`. If it exists inside any `frame/iframe`, you need to switch that `frame/iframe` before finding it as :-

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frame/iframe name or id");
```

Answer (score 3):

It's recomanded to not try to find element by button or item text. This can be easy changed while page is still in develop so I would suggest to use click by `id` instead of by text

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("expTo")).click();
```

There is also alternative to click by css for example:

```
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".css-class-name"));
```

All others selectors can be found [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)

Comment: I tried above selectors. But not worked for me. Please provide any other option.

Comment: This way how to find element should be correct. However as @Saurabg Gaur mentioned in his answer there can be issue with `iframe` or you try to click element which is not visible yet. I remember i fight with both options milion times :)